# PySpark: Group by and aggregation of matching values

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, group-by, window-functions

I have a big table like below-

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 2 | In Progress |
| 2 | Start |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 1 | Start |
| 3 | In Progress |
| 3 | Start |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 1 | Start |
| 1 | End |
| 1 | In Progress |
| 1 | End |
| 2 | In Progress |
| 3 | In Progress |
| 3 | End |

In PySpark using functions, want to derive *id-wise counts of each status* in separate columns like below:

| id | start-count | in-progress-count | end-count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Can I make the PartitionBy work in this use-case? If not, what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by and use counts with conditions, sample code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, when

data = [
    (1, "In Progress"),
    (1, "In Progress"),
    (2, "In Progress"),
    (2, "Start"),
    (1, "In Progress"),
    (1, "Start"),
    (3, "In Progress"),
    (3, "Start"),
    (1, "In Progress"),
    (1, "Start"),
    (1, "End"),
    (1, "In Progress"),
    (1, "End"),
    (2, "In Progress"),
    (3, "In Progress"),
    (3, "End"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "status"])

output_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    count(when(df.status == "Start", True)).alias("start-count"),
    count(when(df.status == "In Progress", True)).alias("in-progress-count"),
    count(when(df.status == "End", True)).alias("end-count"),
)

output_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| id|start-count|in-progress-count|end-count|
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|  1|          2|                5|        2|
|  2|          1|                2|        0|
|  3|          1|                2|        1|
+---+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spark `higher` order functions.

- `size(filter(cl, x->x=='start'))` -> filter the array that has only `start` status in it.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','in-progress'),('1','in-progress'),('2','in-progress'),('3','start')],['id','status'])
df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(col("status")).alias("cl")).\
  withColumn("start-count", expr("""size(filter(cl, x->x=='start'))""")).\
    withColumn("in-progress-count", expr("""size(filter(cl, x->x=='in-progress'))""")).\
    show(10,False)
#+---+-----------+-----------------+
#|id |start-count|in-progress-count|
#+---+-----------+-----------------+
#|1  |0          |2                |
#|2  |0          |1                |
#|3  |1          |0                |
#+---+-----------+-----------------
```

- 